# Email Form on Website

Tags: php

I recently decided to brush up on my coding skills (WOW have things changed in ten + years) and I need a little help making the email form function properly.

HERE IS THE HTML:

```
<!-- Contact Contents Starts -->
                <div class="contents">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Form Starts -->
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <div class="form animated" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="1000">
                                <div class="heading">Drop us a line.</div>
                                <form action='js/contact/contact-form.js' method='post' name='ContactForm' id='ContactForm' >
                                    <div id='message_post'></div>
                                    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name *">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
                                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i></span>
                                        <input type="text" name="website" class="form-control" placeholder="Website">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i></span>
                                        <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment *"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group form-buttons"> <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type='submit' value='Submit' name='submitf' id="submitf" style="width:100%;height:40px;"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> SEND</button>
                                        </span> 
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Form Starts -->
                        <div class="space"></div>
                        <div class="space"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Contact Contents Starts -
```

HERE IS THE JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#ContactForm").submit(function(){
        $("#submitf").value='Please wait...';

        $.post("process.php?send=comments", $("#ContactForm").serialize(),
        function(data){
            if(data.frm_check == 'error'){ 

                    $("#message_post").html("<div class='errorMessage'>ERROR: " + data.msg + "!</div>"); 
                    document.ContactForm.submitf.value='Resend >>';
                    document.ContactForm.submitf.disabled=false;
            } else {
                $("#message_post").html("<div class='successMessage'>Your message has been sent successfully!</div>"); 
                $("#submitf").value='Send >>';
                }
        }, "json");

        return false;

    });
});
```

I cannot find the process.php file and i know nothing about writing php.

Comment: Are you using a cms? A framework? If so, which?

Comment: If you don't have a `process.php` and can't write PHP then you either need to learn how to write PHP, find a prewritten script, or use a different server side language that you do know. Teaching you PHP is far too broad of a topic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your JQuery Code tries to `POST` the form data to process.php. So unless that file is present, it will not work.
If you have a different PHP file that should handle the actual processing, change that file name.
If that doesn't help you either, i am afraid you will need to go searching for a script / package / anything that works, and use that.